# Change font color and background in html on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I'm using a small piece of inline HTML code to change the background of a cell color in a table on mouse hover. I use this on specific table cells only, so not all cells need this to happen.

```
<td  bgcolor="#000000" onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'" onmouseout="this.bgColor='black'"  >
```

This works nicely, but I would also like to change the font color.

So that it by default is a black cell with white text

But on mouseover the bgcolor is white and the text is black, how should I do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be great if you use `:hover` pseudo class over the `onmouseover` event

```
td:hover
{
   background-color:white
}
```

and for the default styling just use

```
td
{
  background-color:black
}
```

As you want to use these styling not over all the `td` elements then you need to specify the class to those elements and add styling to that class like this

```
.customTD
{
   background-color:black
}
.customTD:hover
{
  background-color:white;
}
```

You can also use `:nth-child` selector to select the td elements

Comment: but i only want it for specific table cells, not for all table cells.

Comment: how would you define specific table cell? I means which are the specific table cells?

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element (as `::after` is for example)

Comment: I tried above code, however when the mouse is not hovering over the td element then the background is transparant ?

Comment: ah that was just a typo i had, i forgot to place a ;

Answer (score 11):

Either do it with CSS like the other answers did or change the text style color directly via the onMouseOver and onMouseOut event:

`onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'; this.style.color='black'"`

`onmouseout="this.bgColor='black'; this.style.color='white'"`

Comment: well your code works to, at first i was the most clear code i thought but i later decided to go for Sachins answer. When putting it in css the main page code becomes shorter more readable. But still thanks

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It explicitly answers the question 'Change font color and background in html **on mouseover**' (emphasis mine). All the other answers (including Sachin's - which is an excellent solution) provide CSS solutions using the pseudo class `:hover`, but that isn't what the question asked for; it specified **on mouseover**.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use CSS for this:

```
td{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
td:hover{
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
}
```

If you want to use these styles for only a specific set of elements, you should give your `td` a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (or an [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors), if it's the only element which'll have that style).

Example :

### HTML

```
<td class="whiteHover"></td>
```

### CSS

```
.whiteHover{
    /* Same style as above */
}
```

[Here's a reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/%3ahover) for `:hover` pseudo class.

Comment: but i dont want it to happen to all cells, so how then could i use it for only specific cells

Answer (score 0):

```
td:hover{ 
background-color:red;
color:white;
}
```

[I think this is what are you looking for.](http://jsfiddle.net/3d97F/)