# onmouseover of text change background color of numbered circle

Tags: html, css

I want Fill the circle background with white color onmouseover of text , right now when i am hovering on circle background color is changing But i need when i am hovering on text (Choose support Layer) circle background color will change.

Please give me some idea...

```css
.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 14px 17px 12px ;
  background: #afbabc;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide some codes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794433/change-font-color-and-background-in-html-on-mouseover

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @AnkitGupta I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with your option's parent and change on the parent's hover state.

You can type something like `parent:hover child` and that's how you can target your child element when the mouse is hovering over the parent element.

```css
.numberCircle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 60px;
height: 42px;
padding: 14px 17px 12px ;
background: #afbabc;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
color: #666;
text-align: center;
}
.line{
  height:60px;
  }
.line:hover .numberCircle{
  background:lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<div class="line"><span class="numberCircle">1</span> Option 1</div>
<div class="line"><span class="numberCircle">2</span> Option 2</div>
<div class="line"><span class="numberCircle">3</span> Option 3</div>
<div class="line"><span class="numberCircle">4</span> Option 4</div>
```

Comment: Your code is correct need some help by default i want to show first circle selected and if i am hovering on other circle default circle background color will go

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <span class="circle">1.</span>
  <span class="text">Some text</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 2em; height: 2em;
  text-align: center; line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 100%;

  transition: background-color .2s;
}
.outer{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.outer:hover .circle{
  background-color: #999
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzOBRv

Comment: @websmentor.com So please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your code looks like this, just add the [`:hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) selector to the parent (`li` in this case).

```css
body {
  background:gray;  
}

ul {
  margin:20px 0 0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  color:#fff;  
}

.numberCircle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 14px 17px 12px ;
  background: #afbabc;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover .numberCircle {
  background: #fff;
  color:#afbabc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="numberCircle">1</span>
    <span>Support Layer</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```